# SVG animation discard element

Tags: animation, svg, element

help me figure it out.
"Discard" does not work. circle should disappear after 2 seconds

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head> 
                <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
                <title>discard</title> 
            </head>
        <body>
            <svg width="800" height="600">
                <circle id="circle2" cx="400" cy="300" r="100" fill="none" 
                    stroke="green" stroke-width="70" stroke-dasharray="15 15">
                    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate"
                    begin="1s" dur="10s" from="0 400 300" to="-720 400 300"/>
                    <discard begin="2s"/> 
                </circle>   
            </svg>
        </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware no current browser implements discard.

Comment: Half a year ago, this worked in Google Chrome, and I was surprised that the code did not change, but stopped working. End of support?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=984947&sort=-modified&q=discard%20component%3ABlink%3ESVG&can=1

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the circle with `<set begin="2s" attributeName="visibility" to="hidden"/>` instead of `<discard begin="2s"/>`. It does not actually discard the circle, but it has wider compatibility.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head> 
                <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
                <title>discard</title> 
            </head>
        <body>
            <svg width="800" height="600">
                <circle id="circle2" cx="400" cy="300" r="100" fill="none" 
                    stroke="green" stroke-width="70" stroke-dasharray="15 15">
                    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate"
                    begin="1s" dur="10s" from="0 400 300" to="-720 400 300"/>
                    <set begin="2s" attributeName="visibility" to="hidden"/>
                </circle>   
            </svg>
        </body> 
    </html>
```